# Why can't I connect to my remote desktop with rdesktop command?

Tags: remote-desktop

I can connect remote desktop in `remmina` with RDP protocol. It encounters an error when I connect to the remote desktop with `rdesktop` command:

```
rdesktop  192.168.31.21
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyERROR: Failed to open display: :0
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're executing `rdesktop` from a **different** X screen than your running X session. I don't know how and why it happened but the error you're getting indicates exactly that.